# Why lexer rule name word cause parse error

Tags: antlr4

In the lexer,parser below, the
`SELECT AAA FROM TAB`
can be parsed, but
`SELECT ROLE FROM TAB`
cannot be parsed and an error occurs.
`line 1:7 mismatched input 'ROLE' expecting ID`

The fact that 'ROLE' is the same as the name of the lexer rule seems to be causing the error.
However I want to match 'ROLE' with
`ID: [A-Z]+ ;`
and not want to get an error.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
lexer grammar TSqlLexer;

FROM:               'FROM' ;
ROLE:               'ROLE' ;
SELECT:             'SELECT' ;
SPACE:              [ \t\r\n]+    -> skip;
ID:                 [A-Z]+ ;
```

```
parser grammar TSqlParser;

options { tokenVocab=TSqlLexer; }

sql_clause       : select_statement EOF ;
select_statement : SELECT column_name FROM table_name  ;
column_name      : ID ;
table_name       : ID ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lexer is not driven by the parser. It doesn't matter the parser is trying to  match an `ID`, the input `"ROLE"` will always become a `ROLE` token.

If you have keywords that can also be identifiers, do something like this instead:

```
select_statement : SELECT column_name FROM table_name  ;
column_name      : id ;
table_name       : id ;
id               : ID | ROLE ; // add more keywords if needed

FROM             : 'FROM' ;
ROLE             : 'ROLE' ;
SELECT           : 'SELECT' ;
SPACE            : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
ID               : [A-Z]+ ;
```

Comment: Thank you for you good answer.
The problem is solved.